# Проверку существования записи в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

Не записывать, если такая запись уже есть в БД.

Переменные с данными которые нужно записать в БД: `u_id, rec_id , voice`

Таблица `User`:

```
'user_id' , 'recipe_id' , 'voice'
```

Comment: что мешает проверить через select?

Comment: покажите код на примере пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете индекс по этим полям и будет вам счастье.

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD UNIQUE `INDEX_NAME`(`user_id`, `recipe_id`, `voice`);
```

Проверяем, что существует такая запись и если ее нет, то добавляем.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND recipe_id='$recipe_id' AND voice='$voice'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if (!$num_rows) {
   //Инсертим свои данные
}
```

Comment: Так будет же ошибка при попытке добавить.

Comment: Если кто-то ещё может вмешаться, у вас всё равно возможность обгона (race condition). Проверить надо, да, через select. Но может с другого клиента попробовать такого добавить, и поэтому ошибка при попытке добавить - это правильно.

Comment: расширение **mysql_query** [давно устарело и не поддерживается в новых версиях php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php). рекомендуем использовать [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) или [**pdo**](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php).

Answer (score 2):

Можно через select, а можно короче:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `User` (`user_id` , `recipe_id` , `voice`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$recipe_id' , '$voice')
```

Такой подход возможен если у Вас стоит уникальный ключ по какому-либо полю.

Проверить была ли вставлена запись или нет Вы можете при помощи [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

**UPD**

Как верно подметил @IgorKarpenko данный запрос имеет особенность, а именно:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (NULL,1);
```

Строка будет добавлена (в данном случае со значением `event_id` `0`), даже если у столбца `event_id` стоит ограничение `NOT NULL`, что может привести к негативным последствиям. Поэтому следует не забывать про данную особенность при построении запросов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно проиндексровать поля использовать INSERT IGNORE вместо простого INSERT, в таком случае ошибки про неуникальный ключ будут подавляться, а в таблицу вставятся только уникальные записи
Но безопаснее использовать скрипт вида:

```
INSERT 
... 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id = id ;
```

Советую ознакомиться: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update
и https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38817/on-duplicate-key-do-nothing

**UPD: Разверну мысль по поводу небезопасности подавления ошибок.**

Допустим есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_test` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`type_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `indx` (`event_id`, `type_id`)
);
```

Обратите внимание на заданные ограничения NOT NULL.

Добавим строку:

```
INSERT INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (1,1);
```

Теперь варинат с INSERT IGNORE:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (1,1);
```

Получаем предупреждение, строка не вставилась.
В принципе, на этом можно остановиться - соглашусь с пользователем @Alex,  такой вариант может подойти для ряда прикладных задач.

Такой же результат, мы получим при след. запросе:

```
INSERT INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (NULL,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;
```

Нет ошибок, нет предупреждений, строка не вставилась - этот вариант точно так же удовлетворяет условия задачи.

Разница между этими вариантами в следующем запросе:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (NULL,1);
```

Получаем предупреждение и строка вставилась, не смотря на указанное при создании таблицы ограничение NOT NULL. Есть ряд прикладных задач, где подобное поведение может привести к нарушению логики работы приложения и хранения данных.

А запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `tmp_test` (`event_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (1,NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;
```

Вернет ошибку:

```
(1048): column `type_id` cannot be null
```

Логика не нарушается, данные целые. Иногда лучше прервать работу приложения, чем позволить ему работать в неопределенном состоянии (или обработать исключение, вернуть приложение в определенное состояние и продолжить выполнение программы).

Автор вопроса может теперь решить, какой вариант лучше подходит для его случая.

Comment: зачем обновлять данные если это не требуется ?

Comment: ознакомьтесь с отмеченным ответом по ссылке: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update. IGNORE подавляет ошибки, что не всегда безопасно.

Comment: в курсе, вместо ошибок будут предупреждения, однако все зависит от условий задачи - это и имелось ввиду в первом комментарии.

Comment: не может, а подойдет и как минимум для решения **данной** задачи =) верное замечание по вставке `null` при `insert ignore`.